# How do I create an array of the objects that are on the outside of a cluster?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, drawing

Hello dear programmer,

I am working on a little program (in C#) where some objects are clustered. The clusters can change shape in the program but I always want a line between (or even around) the outer objects (a little bit like a cell wall in biology). My approach is trying to get the coordinates of the outer objects in an array and draw a polygon between the coordinates. Can anyone give me a suggestion on how I can achieve this or show me an example of how it is done elsewhere?

Thanks for your help!

A

Comment: Start with Wiki:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perimeter.  The solution will depending on setting range limit for x & y. The range is the minimum size of each line in your perimeter object. The simple approach is the perimeter will consist of only vertical and horizontal lines.  the more complicated approach is the perimeter has diagonal lines. First identify the perimeter cells by comparing each cell with every other cells looking for a min/max x/y within the range.  Have 4 markers for each cell:max x,max y,min x,min y.  When comparing two cells only change 4 markers when new min/max is found.

Comment: Dear jdweng, thanks for your answer. I figured it might have to be done in a way like that. I was hoping there would be an easier (less heavy) approach to do this. In my programm I might end up with 1000 of those clusters containing 3 to a few 100 objects and I would like the lines to be rendered in a blink of the eye. Is this maybe a bit to farfetched for a normal computer?